# Difference in use cases of near deploy vs near dev-deploy

Tags: nearprotocol

If I understand it correctly, `near dev-deploy` creates temporary dev-123-456 account for smart contract while `near deploy` will use testnet account.

What are different use cases of when to use `near deploy` to testnet and `near dev-deploy`?

Answer (score 5):

`near dev-deploy` is used during development to help save time while creating, deleting and recreating accounts.

NEAR accounts allow contract redeployment (you can redeploy a contract as many times as you like if you have a `FullAccess` key attached to the account)

but deploying a contract does **NOT** change account state

this can leave developers with an updated contract but old state on the account which is a common source of errors for beginners

to help people avoid this problem of mismatched contract code and state during development, the `near dev-deploy` command was introduced

you use it to quickly deploy a contract to a generated account name which you can then delete and recreate from scratch anytime because you don't care about the account name

---

`near deploy` is the command you would use when you have a specific account in mind to which you want to deploy your contract

this makes perfect sense when deploying a version of your contract that you want to share with others on TestNet and definitely when moving to MainNet